# devexpress dropdown list inaccessible on mobile issue

Tags: c#, iphone, devexpress, dropdown

So currently I have a web app that works perfectly fine on my desktop, but when I access this web app through mobile using an iphone (desktop version in mobile), I noticed that devexpress is not handling my dropdown list correctly (Look at screenshot attached/link).

[desktop version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQmD4.png)

[mobile version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhx9v.png)

For mobile when I click the last row dropdown to enter a different item, the list of items does not show,  it actually gets hidden underneath the grid system. I tried styling and using z-index but had no luck at all, but on the desktop version everything seems to work perfectly fine.

​I have attached images comparing the two, One is mobile and the other is for desktop. I am not sure why in the mobile my dropdown list gets hidden or doesn't show correctly.

NOTE**** this only happens for the dropdown list on the ​LAST ROW OF THE GRID SYSTEM.

I don't think this is a styling issue, I feel like its a devexpress issue. The class is also the dxeEditArea class on the dropdown box.

Thank you ​

Comment: have you looked on the DevExpress knowledge base?  if this is related to one of their controls you should be asking them

Comment: Are you using their ASP.NET controls, ASP MVC controls or HTML5 controls?

Comment: I did create a ticket through devexpress, but no one has followed up on it yet. I am using Web Forms ASP.NET